# Best way to exchange message between multiple servers

Tags: php, mysql, database, webserver, load-balancing

I have same web application hosted on multiple web servers (say 5 different servers) for multiple (say 5 ) clients.

And, each of them also have same ticketing system to raise support issues to the administrator (to myself).

Now, problem, Administrator have to login each client websites to check for any raised tickets which is very time consuming and not very efficient.

Although, I could build a central system to just to host ticketing system, but ticketing system also linked with other services and I don't either want to have two different authentication (one for web application and one for ticketing system) either.

Note: There is no centralized database, assume its an web application hosted independently for each clients

Do you have better idea to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: isn't there a centralized database system for 5 servers ? are you speaking about load balancing servers?

Comment: Basically, you can either "push" (=remote systems connect to one central server and upload their stuff there) or "pull" (=make a bot that connects to remotes and collects their updates).

Comment: There is no centralized database, assume it an application hosted independently for each client

Answer (score 0):

According to me a good way to solve this problem is having some services.

Let's imagine you have some controller responsible to return tickets, which returns data in JSON format from the particular server.

So once you have it, you can collect that data either in database  using some CRON calls, or call that services with AJAX every time when the ticket page is requested on some server.

So basically it is the following`

Logged in to second server -> Calling 1, 3, 4, 5 servers' services, and there you go with data needed.